# FloatingActionButton разное отображение в разных версиях андроид

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, я использую `FloatingActionButton`

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="right"
        app:expandedTitleGravity="center"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="32dp"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_img"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/collapsing_img"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|start"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Во всех версиях выше `API 16` кнопка отображается как положено, но я запустил приложение в `API 16`, и кнопка не выходит за пределы `CollapsingToolbar`. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Как исправить?

[image: FloatingActionButton]

Comment: Покажите разметку. И подумайте об отказе от поддержки столь древних версий оси

Comment: То есть указывать минимальное API 16 это уже древность? Обновил код

Comment: Это когда это JB стал старикашкой? Леденец появился и понеслась сладкая жизнь? Да их больше чем кит катов!

Comment: Min API 9! Вот что я скажу